# VB.NET - Get a value from a field in a Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My game saves a score into the field of a database according to the user who has logged in. **How do I retrieve the value of the score from the field and output it to a textbox?** The user who is logged in is displayed in a textbox. The code that allows the user to log in is below. I need to retrieve the score value before `frmGame.Show()`.
**Thanks for help**

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    'Check if username or password fields are empty
    If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        'Declare connection to database
        'OleDb = Object Linking and Embedding, Database
        Dim connDB As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        'Location of Access Database
        connDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Year 12\Information Technology\Programming\WindowsApplication2\userDatabase.accdb"

        Try
            'Holds the username and password 
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE User='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Pass= '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

            'Open database connection
            sqlCom.Connection = connDB
            connDB.Open()
            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

            'If username and password validated then display game form
            If sqlRead.Read() Then
                Me.Hide()
                frmGame.Show()
            Else
                'Authentication failure message 
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                txtUsername.Text = ""
                txtPassword.Text = ""
                txtUsername.Focus()
            End If

            'Database connection failure message 
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Connection to User Database failed" & ex.Message, "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is stored the score value? Where do you want to show that value?

Comment: What is not working for you? What error messages are you receiving?

Comment: I need to retrieve the score value from tbl_User where the username is txtUser.text